# PHP garbage collection triggered by cron not working

Tags: php, session, cron, garbage-collection

I'm trying to set up a cron-triggered garbage collection using session_gc() as [discussed here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/php/cleanup-php-sessions-like-a-pro), however no garbage is being collected, it seems.

The cron runs a php file with this in it:

```
session_start();
$result = session_gc();
session_destroy();
```

...and writes the result to a log. The result is always 0. However, if I just run the php file manually from a browser, it results in a large number (representing the amount collected).

I know the cron job is working and the php script is running, since it's writing to the log. Why doesn't the garbage collection work when triggered via cron job, yet does when triggered manually?

I read that the script "should be executed by the user of web server process" ... how do I make sure of that? I tried changing the ownership of the php file to the same as the folders holding the website where the sessions are run. The script permissions are set at 664.

I'm using [Crunz scheduler](https://github.com/lavary/crunz) to actually trigger the php script, but I know it's working as well.

Thanks for any help.

NOTE: I ended up trying the "curl" method, as Nigel Ren suggested in the comments, and that seems to be the only thing that works. (Created a cron job using curl to run the php file.)

Comment: Do you run the cron job in a CLI or as a web script?

Comment: Nothing is done via CLI. The Crunz scheduler is triggered by a cron job, which then calls the PHP script with the contents shown above. That's what gives a result of 0 each time. If I trigger that same PHP script by just entering the PHP url in my browser, it returns a positive result. Btw, I have also tried using a shell script triggered by a cron job, which didn't work either.

Comment: Might sound odd, but can you try making the cron job use curl (or similar) to access this as a web page.

Comment: I think you might be looking for set* bits: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits. Changing file ownership by itself won't affect the effective uid/gid of the process once it's spawned.

Comment: @parttimeturtle, I think changing set bits doesn't work on a php file. I tried it, and it was highlighted in red afterwards (when listing the files via SSH). I let the cron run, and it still didn't work. Reading up on it, it seems that only works for bin files and such. Anyway, I did try changing the chmod from 664 to 775 and even 777, but that didn't work either. I've also tried every combination of file ownership possible on my system, from root:root to nginx and my group. Nothing seems to make any difference.

Comment: @Nigel Ren, I haven't tried that yet, but the Cruz scheduler does run the file via the php bin, which would accomplish the same thing, right?

Comment: @jamminjames Again file ownership has no effect on what uid/gid the process spawns under. PHP itself also has the ability to change the effective uid/gid of an already-spawned process. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setuid.php

Comment: There are potentially 2 php binaries, the cli and the web based.  If you run it via the cli version, it will only operate on the cli versions sessions.

Comment: @Nigel Ren, as I said, I am not running it via cli.

Comment: @parttimeturtle, So, I ran `echo posix_getuid()` in the file and got an id. Now what do I do with that info?

Comment: I've tried setting uid/gid with `sudo chmod g+s` and `sudo chmod u+s`, no change in result.